# DynamicVIewPanel ignores oncolumnclick if customized

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Using a DynamicViewPanel and a customizer bean to change the column that is a link. The column that is the first column in the view is being hidden via the bean using the setRendered() method and another column is made the link using the setDisplayAs("link") method. That works fine but the oncolumnclick event never fires. It appears that the event is tied to the original column and not the "new" link column.

Anyway to tie an event to the "new" link column? I need to set a scoped variable before navigating to the new XPage.

Howard

Got this to work using something like Maire suggested.

In the method,   public void afterCreateColumn(FacesContext context, int index,
          ColumnDef colDef, IControl column) {,  I added this code to get the event from the column I was hiding:

```
//Hide the first column in this view
        if(dynamicColumn.getColumnName().equalsIgnoreCase("$2")){
          //dynamicColumn.setRendered(false);
            dynamicColumn.setDisplayAs("hidden");
            String type = dynamicColumn.getChildren().get(0).getClass().toString();
            DebugToolbarBean.get().info("type is " + type);
            event = (XspEventHandler) dynamicColumn.getChildren().get(0);
        }
```

I also created an event variable to hold this:

```
com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler event;
```

Then, where I made the column I wanted to be a link I added:

```
if (dynamicColumn.getColumnName().equalsIgnoreCase("OrderDate")){
          //make it a link
          dynamicColumn.setDisplayAs("link");

          DebugToolbarBean.get().info("make OrderDate a link");
          if (event != null){
              dynamicColumn.getChildren().add(event);
              DebugToolbarBean.get().info("adding event");
          } else {
              DebugToolbarBean.get().info("event is null");
          }

      }
```

Comment: If XPages is acting weird on you then maybe you could write a client side onclick event that calls an JSON-RPC.  The JSON-RPC can then set the scoped variable on the backend.

Comment: That is a possibility since I can add CSJS to the column in the customizer bean but the issue would be getting the value for that row with CSJS. That part might be tricky...

Comment: Tricky but possible. You can capture the value through jQuery and pass it to the JSON-RPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you could try moving the location of the xp:eventHandler in the control tree.

As in, the initial dynamically generated control tree is like:

```
xp:viewColumn id="column1" displayAs="link"
    xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
xp:viewColumn id="column2" displayAs="text"
```

And your code is changing it to switch the displayAs values:

```
xp:viewColumn id="column1" displayAs="text"
    xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
xp:viewColumn id="column2" displayAs="link"
```

but the xp:eventHandler would still listen for clicks on its ancestor column1.

You could move the eventHandler in the customizerBean, like so:

```
public void afterCreateColumns(FacesContext context, UIDynamicViewPanel panel) {
    UIViewColumn col1 = (UIViewColumn) panel.getChildren().get(0);
    UIViewColumn col2 = (UIViewColumn) panel.getChildren().get(1);
    UIEventHandler eventHandler = (UIEventHandler) col1.getChildren().get(0);
    // move the eventHandler to col2.
    col2.getChildren().add(eventHandler);
}
```

[The code in ExtLib that creates the control tree structure is:
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.DominoDynamicColumnBuilder.createColumn(...) ]

Comment: Maire, thanks, not sure what classes to import for the UIViewColumn and UIEventHandler? I get 

    Exception

    com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler incompatible with   com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewColumn

My imports were:
    import com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler;
    import com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewColumn;

In the customizer bean I already have a method signature called   public void afterCreateColumn(FacesContext context, int index,
       ColumnDef colDef, IControl column)  which I use to hide the column and set the other column as a link. Would I use both afterCreateColumn?

Comment: Maire, thanks, found the com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler class and used that and your code. See my working code above in my question edits. Howard